# Changing data in mongoose callback function before sending it with response

Tags: javascript, mongodb, express

I am using mongoose package to pull data out of MongoDB (using cb) and send to browser. One of the properties I am pulling is a date object, I try to change this date object to a String before passing to HTML file, however it does not get reassigned. Any reasons why?

I tried reassigning to a different Date() and that does reassign the variable.
Do Schema rules still apply when accessing/changing data in callback? How can I change this variable to a string that represents a date?

```
function index(req, res, next) {
    Flight.find({},function(err, flights){
        flights.forEach(function(flight){
            flight.departs = 'any string';
            console.log(flight.departs);
        })
        res.render('flights/index', {flightDocs: flights, title: 'Flights', moment});
    })
}
```

Console shows this - it's the date objects originally in the database.

```
2020-11-17T23:56:00.000Z
2019-11-17T22:01:00.000Z
2019-11-17T23:05:00.000Z
2019-11-17T22:03:00.000Z
2020-11-18T00:01:00.000Z
2020-11-18T00:01:00.000Z
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`flight` is a mongoose model, not a normal object, then I think, when you call `flight.departs`  getter of the model will be call to return their value.

You have convert a model to a json object, then edit the new json object if you want.

```
function index(req, res, next) {
  Flight.find({}, function (err, flights) {
    const flightsResult = flights.map(function (flight) {
      const json = flight.toJson(); // convert doc to json object
      json.departs = 'any string'; // update json property
      console.log(flight.departs);
      return json;
    });
    res.render('flights/index', { flightDocs: flightsResult, title: 'Flights', moment });
  })
}
```

Or, just tell Mongoose that all you need is a plain JavaScript version of the returned doc by using [lean()](https://mongoosejs.com/docs/api.html#query_Query-lean) in the query chain.

```
function index(req, res, next) {
  Flight.find({}).lean().exec(function (err, flights) {
    flights.forEach(function (flight) {
      flight.departs = 'any string';
      console.log(flight.departs);
    })
    res.render('flights/index', { flightDocs: flights, title: 'Flights', moment });
  })
}
```

Comment: Yes, both those methods work.lean() is definitely a cool method I will be utilizing more. Thank you.